# R Shiny - Putting a Reactive Function into a Data Frame

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

In my app, I am bringing in data and getting it to kick out to datatables for display. However, I then need that data to be available for use with *tidygraph* which doesn't seem to play well with reactive data. As such, I'd like to make the "reactive" static. Is there a way?

For the record, I 100% am not looking to render this as a data table for display. I already have all that functionality. Whenever I search for a response to this issue, everyone's advice seems to end with *renderDT* but not put the OP's data back into a workable dataframe.

In short, how do I see reactive data in a frame?

I've tried about every *reactive* command option there is. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please have a look [how to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), i.e. a minimal running shiny app that displays your problem. Then it's easier to help you, thanks!

Comment: I get why you suggested this but I am not even sure how to create a minimal example of this issue. The narrative really explains it. If it helps, the last error I received said, "Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'as.igraph' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')". As my problem states, I just need to know how to move a table of data out of the "reactive" class and keep it for use versus rendering it out for display.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It may be helpful to show what code you have used so far to illustrate the problem and why you are having issues.

Comment: It sounds like you pass your `reactive_object` unevaluated to `igraph` instead of evaluated (`reactive_object()`), but without code/an example it's difficult to tell

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I simply had to place the problematic action into the reactive, which seems logical but I didn't think it would allow me to do what I wanted. Nevertheless, I have achieved the full functionality that I wanted for this stage.

Thanks for the guidance to those who responded.